# Помогите исправить ошибку в коде

Tags: массивы, visual-c++, матрицы, c++

Дана квадратная матрица. Надо найти ее определитель. Где именно я ошиблась?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    int** mas;
    int n;

    void init()
    {
        mas = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = new int[n];
        }
    }

    void fill()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                mas[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            }
        }
    }

public:

    Matrix(int x, int y)
    {
        n = x;
        n = y;
        init();
        fill();

    };

    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << mas[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void opred()
    {
        int p=0, k,t;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            t=1;
            while(mas[i][i]==0)
            {
                // переставить i-ую и (i + t)-ую строки
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    mas[i][j]=k;
                    mas[i][j]=mas[i+t][j];
                    mas[i+t][j]=k;
                }
                p++;
                t++;
            }
            for (int m=i+1; m<n; m++)
            {
                // вычесть из m-ой строки i-ую так, чтобы создать 0
                // под клеткой (i, i)
                k=mas[m][i]/mas[i][i];
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                {
                    mas[m][j]-=mas[i][j]*k; 
                }
            }
        }
        k = pow(-1.0, p);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            k*=mas[i][i];
        }
        cout<<"Определитель матрицы ="<<k<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int x, y;
    cout << "Введите количество строк: ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов: ";
    cin >> x;
    Matrix a(x,y);
    a.print();
    a.opred();
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какой способ вы используете? Гаусса здесь не наблюдаю вроде. 

>opred 

Это не профессионально. Более логично было бы назвать `determinant`, или `getDeterminant()`

Comment: Мало ли где ошибка. Например, в `mas[i][j]=k;` — чему, по-вашему, равно `k`?

Comment: Затем, цикл `while(mas[i][i]==0)` — где гарантия, что он завершится? (Например, если матрица вся из нулей, что будет?)

Comment: @ua6xh, это именно попытка вычисления по Гауссу. Но плохая попытка. В классе отсутствует необходимый в данном случае деструктор.

Comment: @BuilderC: А ещё код модифицирует матрицу при вычислении детерминанта. Фе!

Comment: @VladD, не понял, а что в этом плохого?

Comment: @BuilderC: Ну представьте себе. Взяли вы у кого-то класс `Matrix` и не знаете, что там внутри. Положили туда элементы. Вычислили детерминант. И вдруг элементы сами по себе «прыгнули». Абсурд, правда? Вы ж не просили менять элементы, вы надеетесь, что где вы их положили, там они и будут, и что простой подсчёт детерминанта — неразрушающая операция. Вот.

Comment: @VladD, я надеюсь, что этот умозрительный класс снабжен копирующим конструктором, и я могу работать с копией. И, потом, кому нужен простой подсчет определителя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Боюсь, что Ваш определитель часто будет нулем, поскольку элементы матрицы int, и при целочисленном делении меньшего на большее... А надо бы double. Можно, конечно, и с целыми, но придется создавать класс ДРОБЬ с числителями и знаменателями.
2. Поиск главной строки ведите не по нулевому значению элемента, а по максимальной абсолютной величине оного.
3. Не вижу освобождения памяти в Вашем коде.

Только потому, что у меня внучка Машенька:

```
double TMatrix::Determinant()
{
  double d = 1.0;
  for(int i = 0; i < line; i++)
  {
    //Поиск главной строки
    int lmax = i;
    for(int j = i + 1; j < line; j++)
        lmax = fabs(m[j][i]) > fabs(m[lmax][i])? j: lmax;
    if(lmax > i)
    {
      SwapLines(lmax, i);
      d = -d;
    }
    d *= m[i][i];
    if(fabs(d) < 1.0e-10)
      return 0.0;
    //Конец поиска главной строки

    //Начало прямого хода
    for(int j = i + 1; j < col; j++)
    {
      m[i][j] /= m[i][i];   //единственное деления
      for(int k = i + 1; k < line; k++)
        m[k][j] -= m[i][j] * m[k][i];
    }
    //Конец прямого хода
  }
  return d;
```